# Any ways to associate form controls of a booking form?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I was tasked to create a booking form where customers can go on to select a number of items across any date ranges. The form consists of cells, each containing select and input element.

I wrote HTML including `select` and button type `input` with a class name of enddate along with JS as follows:

```js
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('#calendar select'),
enddates = document.querySelectorAll('#calendar input.enddate'),
startdate = document.querySelectorAll('#calendar input.enddate');
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < enddates.length; i++) {
        enddates[i].style.display = 'none';
        console.log(enddates[i]);
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        selects[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            for(let j = 0; j < enddates.length; j++) {
                enddates[j].style.display = 'block';    
            }
            if(selects[i].value) {
                for(let j = 0; j < selects.length; j++) {
                    selects[j].style.display = 'none';  
                }
                selects[i].style.display = 'block'; 
            
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I cannot figure out how to associate the select element with the input.enddate. This is problematic because unless I provide a way to group each select with its associated input elements, the form cannot send `$_POST` data for specific select elements. Please help me associate a select element with associated input elements.

Comment: It would be useful to see the HTML, but you should be able to use numeric or named indices for your form fields. E.g. `select[0]`, `start_date[0]`, `end_date[0]`, etc.